# Can I import an externally hosted file with sass?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, cdn

Using Sass (SCSS) / Compass, is it possible to import some CSS/SCSS into your code from an externally hosted file?

I am hosting a jQuery plugin on a CDN and want to keep the CSS in the same location so I don't lose it.  However, I'd also like to have the option to be able to pull the CSS into my code and have it compile within my main CSS rather than pulling in an extra CSS file in my HTML.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 61):

For those of you who came here looking for a way of importing a CDN as a sass `@import` I found the answer here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/246

This is how you do it (using bootstrap as an example):

`styles.scss`

```
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css);
```

Answer (score 19):

**Sass will not compile any files from a remote location**, all files must be accessible from the filesystem (local hard disk, shared network drive, mounted drive, etc.).

**Sass also does not compile CSS files at all**.  https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/556

```
@import "my.css";
```

Compiles to

```
@import "my.css";
```

Perhaps you might be interested in [Compass extensions](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/extensions/)?

Comment: Your answer isn't really related to the question.  He was asking if he could use externally hosted CSS files within Sass, not anything about local CSS files.  I'm pretty sure that it's by design that Sass doesn't compile CSS files into its output file anyway.

Comment: @Ghodmode Maybe you should reread the question:  "I'd also like to have the option to be able to pull the CSS into my code and have it compile within my main CSS".  I don't know how else that could be interpreted.  The location of the file is irrelevant since you get the same results.  Currently, Sass does not do what is being asked.

Comment: @cimmanon Your comment isn't quite correct. Sass will import a .scss file directly into the target file, i.e. it will compile as if you wrote the imported content right inside that file. However, imported .css files, url()s or any import beginning with http:// will compile as `@import`. This means you still have the additional HTTP request that you might be trying to eliminate. The location DOES matter.

Comment: @LogicArtist Isn't that what I said?  Imported CSS files are not compiled into the file at all.  Whether the CSS file is local or remote is irrelevant:  the result is the same (you get a standard CSS `@import` statement in the compiled results).  **Remote** Sass files are also not compiled into the file.

Comment: Using libsass >= 3.2, you can import css directly into the compiled file: https://github.com/sass/libsass/pull/754

Comment: @Alex Yes, but that still won't help if what you want is to import remote files (Sass or CSS) from a remote address like a CDN, which is the point of *this* question.

Comment: Yes, though this was just directed to the second part of your answer that is not correct these days :)

Comment: The fact that LibSass has added non-standard features over the official Ruby Sass version does not mean my answer is incorrect in any way.

Comment: Well, I don't see the OP specifying Ruby-Sass, I don't see you making it explicit that your answer is focused on Ruby-Sass and I'm not quite sure that one can regard Ruby-Sass as some kind of canonical standard in regards of Sass. I'd even place my money on that libsass is used more frequently than ruby-sass, perhaps making it the de facto standard?

Comment: Ruby-sass is now deprecated

Answer (score 7):

You sure can.  In this context, it works exactly as the standard CSS `@import` rule.  Just give it a URL to the CDN-hosted CSS file.

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import

Comment: Am I missing something or does your link explicitly say that it's *not* possible?

Comment: Sass extends the CSS @import rule to allow it to import SCSS and Sass files. All imported SCSS and Sass files will be merged together into a single CSS output file. In addition, any variables or mixins defined in imported files can be used in the main file.

Comment: "whereas `@import "http://foo.com/bar";` would compile to `@import "http://foo.com/bar";` ". If you import an externally hosted Sass/SCSs file, the import will be compiled into the end result as if it were a CSS import.

Answer (score 3):

```
  @import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=#{$family}");
```

1. Imports where the URL ends with .css.

   @import "theme.css";
2. Imports where the URL begins http:// or https://.

   @import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans";
3. Imports where the URL is written as a url().

   ```
   @import url(theme);
   ```
4. Imports that have media queries.

   @import "landscape" screen and (orientation: landscape);

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can import **external** css file using [PostCSS Import URL Plugin](https://github.com/unlight/postcss-import-url). It will pull the external CSS into your code, so you could compile it within your main CSS.

Answer (score 0):

`@import url('https://example.com/path/filename.scss');`

Use import statement to import an external scss file to you local.