# How do I include CSS from a gem using SASS instead of Sprockets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, sprockets

I want to use the [jquery-ui-rails](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails) gem in my rails project, but I'm using SASS imports for my CSS.  How should I import the CSS for jQuery UI?

The css.erb files are under the Ruby installation path hierarchy and I guess the asset pipeline magic is making them available when I serve the app.  I don't see them anywhere in my project path.

I understood that I should use the SASS `@import` statements exclusively instead of mixing them with Sprockets `*= require` directives.

Should I use the [jquery-ui-sass-rails](https://github.com/jhilden/jquery-ui-sass-rails) gem, or is that redundant since the CSS files are already available in the jquery-ui-rails gem?

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0.3.  I'm developing on Windows 8.1 and hosting on Heroku.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947337/can-i-import-an-externally-hosted-file-with-sass

Comment: @cimmanon That question isn't similar to this one.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use [jquery-ui-sass-rails](https://github.com/jhilden/jquery-ui-sass-rails) It's not redundant.  It's designed to work with [jquery-ui-rails](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails) and uses it as a dependency.

One gotcha I discovered is that I can't have both jquery-ui-rails and jquery-ui-sass-rails in my Gemfile because jquery-ui-sass-rails depends on a specific version of jquery-ui-rails and there could be a version mismatch.  I just need to put jquery-ui-sass-rails into Gemfile and it pulls in the correct version of jquery-ui-rails as a dependency.

This is in the Readme for jquery-ui-sass-rails, which I didn't read closely enough.