# Include SASS file from either remote host or absolute directory

Tags: sass

I have a mixins file, which I constantly develop. I use it in every project, but sometimes I need to go back and I not always remember to copy the new file, so it causes confusion (plus, it's really counterproductive, having to copy a single file to each project).

What I thought today, that it would be great if I could `import` a scss file either from remote hos (a dropbox url) or an absolute path. I tried using this:

```
@import 'F:/XAMPP/htdocs/RATIUG/ratiug/reset';
```

and

```
@import 'http://myDropboxLink';
```

but neither worked. Can I solve this somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I import an externally hosted file with sass?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947337/can-i-import-an-externally-hosted-file-with-sass)

Answer (score 0):

When Sass encounters `@import` with a protocol, it assumed that is a CSS directive. So, you have to precise a shared folder.

#### Solution with Sass

If you uses Sass in standalone mode, you can add the `--load-path` argument to precise the shared folder:

```
$ sass --load-path F:/XAMPP/htdocs/RATIUG styles.scss
```

Now, you can call your `reset` mixin:

```
@import "ratiug/reset";
```

#### Solution with Compass

Simply add the shared path in your `config.rb` with [`add_import_path`](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/):

```
sass_dir = "sass"
css_dir = "css"
add_import_path File.expand_path("F:/XAMPP/htdocs/RATIUG")
```