# SASS compiling a file from an http/s location

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to compile a `scss` file using the `sass` command line where the source file resides in a remote location?

i.e.

`sass http://example.com/scss-files/style.scss /path/to/static/assets/output.css`

when I try to do that (with a real source file, of course) I get this error:

`Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - http`

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947337/can-i-import-an-externally-hosted-file-with-sass

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there isn't a way to do this. What you could do is mount your site as a folder using Panic's [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/), compile your SASS and then sync your site with the live site. It isn't ideal, but it's the closest to what you want.