# Can you import sass variables from an externally hosted (cdn) sass file and use it in your project?

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

I have a cdn hosted .scss file that contains a sass variable that I need to access from my code.  The hosted file basically looks like this:

http://hostedsite/styles.scss

```
$styles: (
  $icons: (
    'heart': '\ea01',
    'star': '\ea02',
    'cloud': '\ea03'
  )
)
```

And in my project I'd love to be able to do something like this:

```
@import url("http://hostedsite/icon.scss");

@each $icon, $value in map-get($styles, 'icons') {
  .#{$icon} {
    &::before {
      content: $value;
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do this? I keep getting errors that $styles is undefined.  I'm using gulp-sass if that matters at all.

Answer (score 1):

> Sass will not compile any files from a remote location

([Can I import an externally hosted file with sass?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16947612/9127539))

However you can use a loader (For Webpack: [Webpack Sass Loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader), Universal: [Postcss import url](https://github.com/unlight/postcss-import-url)) with an task runner of your choice that goes through the files and looks for imported url's.

Comment: What's confusing me is this section of Sass docs saying you can do it:

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import

Comment: From the documentation: 'but there are a few circumstances under which it will compile to a CSS @import rule'.

Try importing a css file from your website.