# Import SCSS variables from online url

Tags: import, sass

I've been looking around to see if one can import a `.scss` file by using the url of the directory online?

[image: screengrab of directory url]

I've tried using `@import url('https://<site-url>/api/style/variables.scss')` in my `.scss` files, but this does not seem to import those variables.

Answer (score 0):

Remote file imports in SASS are compiled as CSS imports. The variables do not get considered in a remote location because SASS will treat it as an ordinary CSS file.

See the SASS documentation on imports for more information. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import#plain-css-imports

This question has some information about this subject as well [Can I import an externally hosted file with sass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947337/can-i-import-an-externally-hosted-file-with-sass)